# MIXER - How to convert PC headphone to Line in Signal?

Tags: mixer

Im trying to connect my computer to a mixer board. When I connect it to the mixer from PC i get a very bad sound (sounds distorted or some sort).

Bad sound diagram:

(PC headphone) --> 3.5mm cable --> 1/4 Adapter --> Mixer Line in (neutrik xlr trs combo)

Am I doing this wrongly? Or should I even

Comment: Use the tape input instead.

Comment: What brand / type Mixer? What brand / type sound card ?

Comment: Can you also explain what you mean by distorted - do you mean like an overdriven guitar amp?

Comment: Dont have an tape input because it a usb external soundcard (headphone + mic).

Comment: Are you saying you’re trying to record audio from your computer back into your computer? Is your 1/4” end a TRS or just TS?

Comment: @Timinycricket Just want to connect headphone to a neutrik TRS input.

Comment: @user1148967 the headphone out will be in TRS stereo. The TRS input is not stereo it is balanced; so if the other end of the headphone cable is TRS for stereo that is what the distorted sound is coming from. You’d need a stereo to mono cable or use a stereo input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah you're doing it wrong.

The PC headphone output is a stereo output jack. pinout is :

- Tip: Left
- Ring: Right
- Sleeve: Ground.

In order to connect this to a computer, you need to make an adapter cable.

you will need two XLR's or 1/4 inch adapters.

1/4" adapter or XLR Adapter 1 (Left) will require the following pinout:

- Pin 1 (ground) (Sleeve)
- Pin 2 (Left Signal) (Tip)
- Pin 3 (ground) (Ring)

1/4" adapter or XLR Adapter 2 (Right) will require the following pinout:

- Pin 1 (ground) (Sleeve)
- Pin 2 (Right Signal) (Tip)
- Pin 3 (ground) (Ring)

What you are currently doing (wrong) is connecting the stereo signal directly to the XLR input:

- pin 1 (ground)
- pin 2 (left)
- pin 3 (right).

Because the input is balanced, the signal you are experiencing on the input is actually "L-R" which is the stereo 'difference' signal.